# Windows exec built by nuitka fails by not finding a file

Tags: python, speech-recognition, pyaudio, nuitka

I have a python (11) application running under Windows 10 in a virtual environment. It works fine. However, when I build an executable with nuitka it fails. Here is the relevant code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

    self.recognizer = sr.Recognizer()
    with self.microphone as source:
        self.audio = self.recognizer.listen(source, timeout=2)

    self.text = str(self.recognizer.recognize_google(self.audio))
```

The last statement ('self.text = ...') throws an exception. When I print that exception I get:

```
*[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified*
```

The speech_recognition module requires pyaudio. I followed
suggestions to solve a similar exception (not in the context of nuitka) with pyaudio by installing pipwin and then ran

```
py -m pipwin install pyaudio
```

The nuitka command I am using:

```
py -m nuitka --enable-plugins=tk-inter --standalone --include-module=pyaudio  ./logic/elizaAI.py
```

nuitka gives no build errors. The application runs fine until it hits the above statement. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Python 11? Are you from the distant future?

Answer (score 1):

Nuitka `--include-module` only includes python files. Is there a different required file (txt, csv, other format) that the code is looking for? If so, use `--include-data-files` as part of your Nuitka command.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

1. I got a stack trace where the error occurred; the relevant line in the trace was:
   **elizaAI.dist\speech_recognition\audio.py", line 245, in get_flac_data**
2. I went into audio.py and found logic that was looking for a .exe file:
   **elizaAI.dist\speech_recognition\flac-win32.exe**
3. It **must** find the file in the speech_recognition folder within the nuitka distribution folder.
4. So, I copied the speech_recognition folder to eliza.dist and removed files that were not needed.
5. The application (elizaAI) runs fine now.

The analysis around pyaudio in my original post was not relevant.